# Google Apps Script: Create new rows for cells that contain commas

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Background: 
Users will fill out a google form and separate their answers with commas. I would like to write a script that can separate cells into rows for each comma used; however, I need to do this for multiple columns.

For example, here are screenshots of the concept that I would want:

How it starts[image]

End goal[image]

**And here is my actual data set:**
[My sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCk99.jpg)

**I have columns A through S. I only want to look at columns D through L and check if they have commas. In the picture, you can see that the first three rows of information do not contain commas. I would just like the code to return those values as they are. In row 5, column D through L does contain commas that represent separate responses, and so I would like those values to be split into separate rows in the output.**

This is what I have so far, that I found the bulk of from someone else on Stackoverflow. This code works but **only if you specify one column**.

For example, on a blank google sheet I write `=split_rows(Sheet1!A:S,3)`, which only checks column 3 of my other sheet for commas. I need a code that will do the same but for several columns and split up the values.

```js
function split_rows(anArray, splitColumnIndex) {
  var output = [];
  for (i in anArray){                                                 // for each row
    var current_cell = anArray[i][splitColumnIndex];                  // current cell in loop
    if (current_cell.toString().indexOf(",")>-1) {                    // if the cell in the designated column contains a comma,  
      var splitArray = current_cell.split(",");                       // split values in specified column
        for (j in splitArray){                                          // for each split cell value
         var row = anArray[i].slice(0);                                // take a copy of source row 
         row[splitColumnIndex] = alltrim(splitArray[j]);               // replace comma separated value with current split value
         output.push(row);                                             // push new row to output
       } 
    }

    else {
      var row = anArray[i].slice(0); 
      output.push(row);
    }
  }
      return output;
  }
 
function alltrim(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
```

Here is an example of my sheet; 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mgqKriAxf6-hAPNJ9Um8i9SD22TxDXVKM8llRn0sCS4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to obtain the output image of "[End goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAxPR.jpg)" from the input image of "[How it starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p0qI.jpg)".
- You want to use the script as a custom function.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I used the following flow. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

1. Retrieve values.
2. When the values of column "A", "B" and "C", split the values of column "B" and column "C" by `,`.
3. When the length of column "B" and "C" is the same, create 2 dimensional array by putting each value to each row.

   - From your input image, I supposed that the numbers of `,` for column "B" and "C" are the same.
4. Put the converted values.

#### Modified script:

```
function split_rows(anArray) {
  var res = anArray.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    if (e.slice(0, 3).every(String)) {
      var colB = e[1].split(",").map(function(f) {return f.trim()});
      var colC = e[2].split(",").map(function(f) {return f.trim()});
      if (colB.length == colC.length) {
        var temp = colB.map(function(g, k) {
          return [e[0], g, colC[k]];
        });
        Array.prototype.push.apply(ar, temp);
      }
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  return res;
}
```

#### Result:

When the values of your input image are used, the result is as follows.

[image]

#### Note:

- I prepared this modified script using your input and output images.
- Although you use the range of `Sheet1!A:S`, it seems that there are no values from column "D" to "S"i n your input image. So in this modified script, the values from column "A" to "C" are used.

  - In you want to use the values from column "D" to "S", can you provide the information of about the converted result?

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

If this was not the result you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it. At that time, can you provide the detail information you want?

### Edit:

For your 2nd question, above script was modified using your shared Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

```
function split_rows2(anArray) {
  var res = anArray.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    var splitted = e.slice(3, 12).map(function(f) {return f.toString().split(",").map(function(g) {return g.trim()})});
    var temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < splitted[0].length; j++) {
      temp.push(e.slice(0, 3).concat(splitted.map(function(f) {return f[j] ? (isNaN(f[j]) ? f[j] : Number(f[j])) : ""})).concat(e.slice(12, 20)));
    }   
    Array.prototype.push.apply(ar, temp);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  return res;
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will be at work next week and will try that out and let you know if it works!

Comment: @LRed Thank you for replying. If the result was not what you want, when you provide a sample Spreadsheet you want, I would like to check it.

Comment: How could I modify this with the following info: I have columns A to S, I only want to check if columns D through L have commas. (Also, if there is a row with no commas I just want to print that row back out as it is) Thanks!

Comment: @LRed Thank you for replying. 1. At first, can I ask you about whether my answer was resolved your initial question? Because my answer is for your initial question which is using the column "A" - "C". 2. About ``I only want to check if columns D through L have commas``, this is new question. I cannot understand what you want to do. Can you provide a sample spreadsheet including the detail information about your new question? If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. I would like to also resolve your new question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for your response. I checked your answer and it does resolve the initial question. Originally, I asked demonstrating an example with columns A-C for simplicity. I attached my updated question in the bold text above, as I am having trouble now using this code to achieve my separating of columns D through L. If any more clarification is needed please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: @LRed Thank you for replying and updating. In order to correctly understand your new question, I would like to ask 3 questions before I modify the script. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @LRed 1. When the value doesn't include ``,``, you want to put the value which is not splitted. In my script, this can be done. 2. In your initial question, you wanted to split the values by ``,`` at the column "B" and "C", in your new question, how about this? 3. About `` I only want to look at columns D through L and check if they have commas.``, I cannot understand this. Because in your sample image, I cannot see the whole situation. Can you provide a sample spreadsheet including the detail information about your new question? Of course please remove your personal information.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I have added an example sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mgqKriAxf6-hAPNJ9Um8i9SD22TxDXVKM8llRn0sCS4/edit#gid=0

Comment: in this example sheet, the tab "The Original Data" is how it starts. I want it to become "The Goal" tab. The background of my project is that users will fill out a google form for a request to setup a printer. However, they may be requesting one or more printers at a time, each request being separated by commas. In order to analyze this information, we want the printer request to be separated out one per row in google sheets ('The Goal' tab). When I use your code it works for the original example I put out, but I am getting an error with this updated data set. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @LRed Thank you for replying. I could understand your 2nd question. So I added a modified script. Could you please confirm it? This is a simple script. So please modify to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function split_rows(anArray, splitColumnIndex) {
  var output = [];
  for (i in anArray){                                                 // for each row
    var current_cell = anArray[i][splitColumnIndex];                  // current cell in loop
    if (current_cell.toString().indexOf(",")>-1) {                    // if the cell in the designated column contains a comma,  
      var splitArray = current_cell.split(",");                       // split values in specified column
        for (j in splitArray){                                          // for each split cell value
         var row = anArray[i].slice(0);                                // take a copy of source row 
         row[splitColumnIndex] = alltrim(splitArray[j]);               // replace comma separated value with current split value
         output.push(row);                                             // push new row to output
       } 
    }

    else {
      var row = anArray[i].slice(0); 
      output.push(row);
    }
  }
      return output;
  }
 
function alltrim(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).